# Convergence issue dirichlet model JAGS, implemented in R

Tags: r, bayesian, convergence, jags, dirichlet-distribution

I have data on the relative abundances of 3 species, stored in the matrix `r.spp.y`. Species 1 has a negative relationship with the variable `mat`, and species 2 and 3 have a positive relationship with the variable `mat`:

```
#Simulate some species relative abundance data.
n <- 100
y1 <- round(rnorm(n, 100, 5)) 
mat <- rnorm(length(y1), 10, 3)
y1 <- y1 + round(mat*-3)
y2 <- round(rnorm(n, 100, 5))
y3 <- round(rnorm(n, 100, 5))
spp.y <- as.matrix((data.frame(y1,y2,y3)))
r.spp.y <- spp.y / rowSums(spp.y)
```

Here is a plot to show these relationships exist:

```
#show there are relationships with mat.
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
for(i in 1:ncol(r.spp.y)){
  plot(r.spp.y[,i] ~ mat)
  abline(lm(r.spp.y[,i] ~ mat), lwd = 2)
  rsq <- summary(lm(r.spp.y[,i] ~ mat))$r.squared
  txt <- paste0('R2 = ',round(rsq,2))
  mtext(txt, side = 3, line = -2, adj = 0.05)
}
```

[image]

I fit a multivariate model to these data using the dirlichet distribution, which is the multivariate generalization of the beta distribution using the `runjags` package in R. Code below.

```
dirlichet.model = "
model {
#setup priors for each species
for(j in 1:N.spp){
m0[j] ~ dnorm(0, 1.0E-3) #intercept prior
m1[j] ~ dnorm(0, 1.0E-3) #      mat prior
}

#implement dirlichet
for(i in 1:N){
for(j in 1:N.spp){
log(a0[i,j]) <- m0[j] + m1[j] * mat[i]
}
y[i,1:N.spp] ~ ddirch(a0[i,1:N.spp]) 
}

} #close model loop.
"

jags.data <- list(y = r.spp.y,mat = mat, N = nrow(r.spp.y), N.spp = ncol(r.spp.y))
jags.out <- run.jags(dirlichet.model,
                     data=jags.data,
                     adapt = 200,
                     burnin = 2000,
                     sample = 2000,
                     n.chains=3,
                     monitor=c('m0','m1'))
out <- summary(jags.out)
```

When I look at the model parameter summary I see two things: (1) none of the chains really converged, indicated by the prsf values. (2) None of the parameter 95% credible intervals for mat are different from zero. Increasing sample size or running a longer JAGS simulation does not change this outcome. Output printed here:

```
          Lower95        Median     Upper95          Mean         SD        Mode       MCerr MC%ofSD SSeff
m0[1]  5.35768574  5.8718514712 6.228604005  5.8278869822 0.28491858  5.99532850 0.050381909    17.7    32
m0[2]  5.34849586  5.8649746778 6.225999953  5.8255381716 0.28831543  6.01183353 0.058322339    20.2    24
m0[3]  5.30951948  5.8417698981 6.195775429  5.7972049003 0.29268382  5.96165385 0.056296339    19.2    27
m1[1] -0.07914617 -0.0363984822 0.008964854 -0.0366993309 0.02742381 -0.01897293 0.006479847    23.6    18
m1[2] -0.04133772  0.0001891246 0.045319610  0.0007892048 0.02775694  0.01978320 0.006837205    24.6    16
m1[3] -0.03889988  0.0033254536 0.049436277  0.0028891798 0.02820870  0.02239507 0.006558280    23.2    19
          AC.10     psrf
m0[1] 0.9043977 7.045678
m0[2] 0.9117633 7.159424
m0[3] 0.9177679 7.143409
m1[1] 0.9345297 5.923798
m1[2] 0.9440124 5.907549
m1[3] 0.9479331 5.925029
```

HOWEVER: Looking at the predicted vs. observed plots, the model parameters do a reasonable job fitting the data, despite the lack of convergence! So, it seems there are multiple parameter combinations that can generate this outcome. Whats the best way to handle this problem? Its clear that the `mat` predictor is important for modeling these relative abundances, but I cannot conclude this from these parameter credible intervals. Model fits visualized here:

```
#Get predicted values for each species.
pred.list <- list()
data <- as.matrix(data.frame(rep(1,nrow(r.spp.y)),mat,map))
for(i in 1:ncol(r.spp.y)){
  a <- c('m0','m1','m2')
  to.grep <- paste0('[',i,']')
  to.grep <- paste0(a,to.grep)
  preds <- out[rownames(out) %in% to.grep,]
  pred.list[[i]] <- exp(data %*% preds[,4])
}
pred.list <- (as.matrix(do.call('cbind', pred.list)))
pred.list <- pred.list / rowSums(pred.list)

#Plot predicted vs. observed and the 1:1 line.
par(mfrow = c(1,3))
for(i in 1:ncol(r.spp.y)){
  plot(r.spp.y[,i] ~ pred.list[,i])
  r.sq <- summary(lm(r.spp.y[,i] ~ pred.list[,i]))$r.squared
  abline(0,1, lwd = 2)
  txt <- paste0('R2 = ',round(r.sq,2))
  mtext(txt, side = 3, line = -2, adj = 0.05)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Martyn Plummer, posted on [the JAGS discussion board](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/discussion/610036/thread/de7dca05/):

When you see this phenomenon - poor mixing but good predictions of observable quantities - it means your model is unidentifiable. This is a bad situation to be in because you cannot use traceplots or more formal diagnostics to check convergence.

Below is a version of your model in which all parameters are identifiable (there are 5 parameters in this version instead o f 6). The parameterization has also been optimized for mixing. I have also reconstructed the original parameterization `m0`, m1. In this version `m1[1]=0`.

```
model {
   #setup priors for each species
   alpha ~ dnorm(0, 1.0E-3)
   beta0[1] <- 0
   beta1[1] <- 0
   for (j in 2:N.spp) {
      beta0[j] ~ dnorm(0, 1.0E-3) #intercept prior
      beta1[j] ~ dnorm(0, 1.0E-3) #mat prior
   }

   #implement dirlichet
   for (i in 1:N){
      for (j in 1:N.spp){
         log(a0[i,j]) <- alpha + beta0[j] + beta1[j] * (mat[i] - mean(mat))
      }
      y[i,1:N.spp] ~ ddirch(a0[i,1:N.spp]) 
   }

   #map to original parameterization
   for (j in 1:N.spp) {
      m0[j] <- alpha + beta0[j] - beta1[j] * mean(mat)
      m1[j] <- beta1[j]
   }

} #close model loop.
```